# How to change a value in an existing window and display it while it changes

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import random

while 1:
    x = randomint(0,25)
    Print(x)
```

Is it possible to Print the "x" Output in a tkinter GUI (just changing the value in the existing window without opening a new Window for a new value)?

I know how to create windows and show text within the window. But I don't understand how to show the value in the window even when the value is changing

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Of course you don't use `print` because that outputs to the console. How it is done depends on the GUI framework you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a value in tkinter, you could use a label and then use the `configure` (or `config`) method to modify the value every time the variable changes.

**Illustrative Code:**

```
from tkinter import *

def update_value(value): 
    global label
    label.configure(text = value)

root = Tk()

#Creating a frame to contain a label and an entry
frame = Frame(root)
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = NSEW)

#Creating the label
label = Label(frame, text = "Label", bg = "black", fg = "white", font = ('Comic Sans', 15))
label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 5, ipady = 5, sticky = EW)

#Creating an entry
entry = Entry(frame, font = ('Comic Sans', 15), bg = "white", fg = "black")
entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 5, ipady = 5, sticky = EW)

#Adding a key binding to entry so that everytime the user hits the enter key, the updated value shows in the label 
entry.bind("<Return>", lambda e: update_value(entry.get()))

root.mainloop()
```

Every time the user makes a change in the entry box and hits the enter key, the label gets updated with the new value in the entry box.

Answer (score 0):

Don't used `while` condition. Using same above, and add widget.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


root = tk.Tk()

x = random.randint(0,25)
print(x)

lb = tk.Label(root,  width=10)
lb.pack() 
lb.configure(text=x)

root.mainloop()
```

Result image:

[image]